# Tkinter align multiple frames

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm having trouble placing three frames using the ttk module. I need to have them at the same size. The left one is placed correctly, but the ones from the right should match the first one's size.

My code is this:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

master = Tk()

frame_labels = ttk.Frame(master, width=500, height=500, relief=SUNKEN)
frame_labels.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky='n')

frame_log = ttk.Frame(master, width=500, height=300, relief=SUNKEN)
frame_log.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=0, pady=10, sticky='n')

credits_frame = ttk.Frame(master, width=500, height=200, relief=SUNKEN)
credits_frame.grid(row=2, column=3, padx=0, pady=10, sticky='n')

master.mainloop()
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: "I need to have them at the same size." Then why are you explicitly giving them different sizes?

Comment: Because my left frames need to be smaller, so that their combined size in the same as the left frame size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first frame (left) needs to span two rows. They all need to have more 'stickiness'.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

master = Tk()

frame_labels = ttk.Frame(master, width=500, height=500, relief=SUNKEN)
frame_labels.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky='news', rowspan=2)

frame_log = ttk.Frame(master, width=500, height=300, relief=SUNKEN, style='My.TFrame')
frame_log.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=0, pady=10, sticky='news')

credits_frame = ttk.Frame(master, width=500, height=200, relief=SUNKEN)
credits_frame.grid(row=2, column=3, padx=0, pady=10, sticky='news')

master.mainloop()
```